# Fix centering last line of elements in fluid container grid to be left aligned while container stays centered

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having trouble left aligning the last row of a 'ul' element inside a fluid container. I have the container centering properly with the page but it ends up centering the last row of elements when they are not fully populated. Can't seem to figure out the solution.

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap at the very core with container-fluid for the outer div. And centering the list elements like so:

```
ul {
    text-align: center;
    list-style:none;
}

ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I've tried using text-align: justify and centering the div with margins but it doesn't seem to move with the resizing of the page. Suggestions?

Here are two screenshots of what's happening:

[image]

[image]

JS Fiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Z9uqQ/

Last line should be aligned left with the same vertical edge as 1.

[image]

Comment: Could you post an example of this somewhere, jsfiddle, jsbin...It would be really helpful.

Comment: Note: There can also be multiples on the last line as shown in screen shots. So :last-child doesn't work.

Comment: I think I got it, check my answer.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/azNyk/ that what u mean?

Comment: @Systembolaget sometimes it can be more than one element so last child doesn't always work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly `margin: 0 auto` will do:

```
ul {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/GdAvm/

Comment: This does not work because on resize of the container, the content is no longer centered. Thanks though.

Comment: I have added a new screenshot depicting what your solution would do with images.

Comment: Notice how it doesn't move the ul to the center. It just leaves everything on the left.

Comment: Sry, I don't see what you mean... Can you make an example with actual images and twitter bootstrap to debug it properly? You can use images from http://placekitten.com to write a quick example.

Comment: No need for bootstrap. http://jsfiddle.net/Z9uqQ/1/ updated. Notice how when you drag the output container to the left, the UL does not re-center itself in the container.

Comment: I've done some test, I think you might need some JavaScript then, can't seem to find a solution with just css.